# consecutive css padding declaration

Tags: css, padding

I'im a bit confused with a css in a template.

There es a part that states the following:

```
.class{ padding:20px 30px;
           padding:20px 25px;}
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The second line will just overwrite the first. However, there are often four padding values when setting left, upper, right and lower as shown in this example:

```
padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
```

Comment: Hi Kyle, I'm familiar with the four usual options, whats the point of overwriting ? 
padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;

padding: 25px 50px 75px;

padding: 25px 50px;

padding: 25px;

Comment: Cool :) Just added it in case.

Answer (score 0):

What are you confused about exactly? If it's why there are two values for one property, it's because it's shorthand for setting values for properties like padding and margin. The first number is the top and bottom padding, the second number is left and right.

If you're confused about why this element doesn't have 30px of padding on either side, it's because the second padding rule is overwriting it.

Comment: Hi brad, Why would you want to overwrite it ? That's my confusion, I know how to use the shorthands, just don't know why theres tu rules are consecutive.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your particular example is a little confusing. I can't think of why you'd ever declare the same rule twice in the same selector, but there are a few situations where you'd need to overwrite, as opposed to just throwing out a rule. Off the top of my head, like a low-specificity selector to set a style, but you have a more specific style you’d like to apply to a similar element.

Comment: I'm reading some else's code, so I'm trying to figure out why overwriting the rules like that can be useful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code below. Browser will consider 2nd padding (`padding:20px 25px;`)

```
.class{
   padding:20px 30px;
   padding:20px 25px;
}
```

**About padding**

.class{ padding: top,right,bottom,left} ( `padding: 10px;`) - Equal padding

.class{ padding: top&bottom left&right }  ( `padding: 10px 20px;`)

.class{ padding: top right bottom left }  ( `padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;`)